# Query local MySql database

Tags: mysql

I'm just getting started with MySql and need to run simple queries on the local database file. But I keep running into the same error: "Can't connect to MySql server on '127.0.0.1'" So wierd since you would think the machine can connect to itself...

I started with [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html), but got stuck at step 15. When I test the connection, it gives me the error.

I don't have the mysqld process running and when trying to start a server instance (hopefully starting said process) I get the error.

There is no my.cnf or my.ini located in my installation folder. I never specified a database file that should be used as data source, for a connection or server, so maybe that's missing?

I'm probably doing something very stupid wrong, but please help me.

[rage]This is so frustrating! Why can't I simply run an sql query while doing data modeling? MySql is a requirement :([/rage]

---

Edit:
The SQL server is up an running, I can connect to it and get in the SQL development part of Workbench. But I cannot select the database I need to connect to, "use DataBaseName" results in "Unknown database 'DataBaseName'". This includes the database name that was auto-generated and is visible in the database modeling view.

This probably has something to do with my server setup, in the configuration wizard at the part "InnoDB Tablespace Settings" everyting is disabled... Seems I'd be able to select my database file here.

Comment: Well, do you have the mysql server installed, and running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is a MySQL client and connects to a MySQL server instance. Server and client(s) can co-exist happily on the same machine.

To run the MySQL server, you normally need to have `mysqld` running. The error that you are reporting `"Can't connect to MySql server on '127.0.0.1'` doesn't seem to be coming from `mysqld`, but from a MySQL client, like Workbench.

Did you download and install the MySQL Server? If not, you can download the community version (currently version 5.1.50) from:

- [MySQL :: Download MySQL Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: Ok so I need the SQL server seperately... Was using only MySql Workbench. Thanks for helping out, I'll post any further problems here.